# How can I compile to Java 6 on Fedora 17 using OpenJDK

Tags: fedora, java

I want to compile to Java 6 using OpenJDK on Fedora 17.  Fedora 17 has OpenJDK7, not OpenJDK6.  I am fine to target compile to Java 6 from Java 7 using -target 1.6 -source 1.6 but to do it right (avoid warning: [options] bootstrap class path not set in conjunction with -source 1.6), I also need -bootclasspath pointing to a Java 6 rt.jar file.  But OpenJDK7 doesn't provide this Java 6 rt.jar file.  How can I correctly compile for Java 6 on FC17?

Answer (score 8):

To install Openjdk 1.6 from Fedora 16 use this command:

```
yum install java-1.6.0-openjdk --releasever=16 --nogpgcheck
```

(`--nogpgcheck` because `yum` complains of not having the key for Fedora 16, maybe there are better ways to solve this)

But this shows, that `java-1.7.0-openjdk` obsoletes `java-1.6.0-openjdk` and skips installation. And it shows that the package `xorg-x11-fonts-Type1` is needed. So I did

```
yum install xorg-x11-fonts-Type1
```

and then I used the openjdk package which `yum` downloaded but refused to install because of the *obsoletes warning*

```
rpm --nodeps -ihv /var/cache/yum/x86_64/16/updates/packages/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0-68.1.11.5.fc16.x86_64.rpm
```

(--nodeps for overriding the *obsoletes warning*)

Now I have both java 1.6 and java 1.7 on my system. Java 1.7 is my default. And Java 1.6 is in `/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64/bin/java`.

PS: **There won't be any conflicts** when you install both 1.7 and 1.6. The reason for removing 1.6 from Fedora 17 was, that OpenJDK6 will [no longer get security updates after November 2012](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.linux.redhat.fedora.general/414703).

Answer (score 2):

You will need OpenJDK 6.

I went to [OpenJDK's install instructions page](http://openjdk.java.net/install/), and they recommended using `yum`

However, I did verify that this was not a build of OpenJDK 1.6 available for Fedora 17 (I am running FC17 as well):

```
yum list java*-openjdk
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Available Packages
java-1.7.0-openjdk.i686    1:1.7.0.5-2.2.1.fc17.9       updates
java-1.7.0-openjdk.x86_64  1:1.7.0.5-2.2.1.fc17.9       updates
```

Here is the same question posted on superuser.com regarding [Install older openjdk 1.6 on Fedora 17](https://superuser.com/questions/441757/how-install-older-openjdk-1-6-in-fedora-17).  The accepted answer was basically to download and install it manually.

If you just want to compile to Java 6, and are not absolutely set on using OpenJDK6, I could help you with step-by-step on doing so using Oracle's JDK 1.6.0_33.  That is the JDK that I use on Fedora 17.

Comment: Thanks.  I prefer to use OpenJDK over Oracle because I like to support open source.  I found a third party copy of OpenJDK6 RPM for FC17.  It won't install because it is obsoleted by my installed OpenJDK7.  So I used "rpm2cpio myopenJDK7.rpm | cpio -idmv" to extract the files, including the desired rt.jar file.  I will have to archive this file if I decide to actually use this build process.  Is this approach the only solution for FC17?  I would expect to be able to install both OpenJDK6 and OpenJDK7 and use "alternatives --config java" to select between them.

Answer (score 0):

Check fedora koji if the build is not there. Google it and search the package.